# Egyptian passport transit through AMS

Tags: transit, egyptian-citizens, yemeni-citizens

Two passengers, one with an Egyptian passport and one with a Yemen passport, want to go from Nairobi to Barbados.
Their flight changes in Schiphol (Amsterdam) airport on the same ticket.
They will stay in the transit lounge.
Are they going to be allowed to transit?

Comment: I have just tried to edit your question for clarity, please feel free to [edit] if I have changed the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the egyptian national, TIMATIC states :

> > Passengers transiting through Amsterdam (AMS) and arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight
> > on the same aircraft or for the first connecting flight to a third
> > country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

The Yemeni national will require a A (Airport Transit Visa) if they don't fullfill the requirements

> > Nationals of Yemen, transiting through Amsterdam (AMS) and arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a
> > flight on the same aircraft or for the first connecting flight to a
> > third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - have a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania or USA, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination

Comment: Just had a similar question and contacted live chat help at Schiphol re two Egyptian passengers, they added the condition that the outbound flight must be on same PNR